# How can I implement iterative incremental training for xgboost? Is it worth doing?

Tags: amazon-s3, xgboost, amazon-sagemaker

I am currently using Xgboost version 1.3.1. There is a custom docker image created out of training scripts and uses SageMaker to run training. Training data is also present in S3. I am facing an issue recently that input data size (data frame) required is more than what the box could support (and there is no higher instance after that). And hence facing OOM issue

I would like to know, if there is a way to resolve this big data issue. Or is it possible to load data iteratively and train using xgb_model option? If so how?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Sage, but to train using XGB incrementally in batches of rows, I do the following. For your case, I guess you will have to see if this helps you make data fit.

1. first, I split the dataframe into X,y, then convert them to np arrays
   e.g.

```
X = pd.read_csv(final_ds)
y = X.pop('target')
X = X.values   # convert to numpy array
y = y.values   # convert to numpy array
```

2. Then do the split into the usual X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid
3. Determine batch size desired, like for example here :

```
size = len(X_train)
print()
print(f'Size of X_train: {size}')
    
print()
for i in range(1, size):                  
    if (size % i) == 0:
        print(f'{i}', end=' ')   # choose from these
```

*The smaller the batch size, the slower the training

4. Split data into batches

```
batch_size = <your selected batch size>
col_size = <the number of columns of X_train>
X_train_batched, y_train_batched = X_train.reshape(-1,batch_size,col_size), y_train.reshape(-1,batch_size)
```

5. Then use the parameter xgb_model in the xgb fit().  This tells the fit() to resume from the last trial.
   e.g.

```
param = <your xgb parmeters>
model_xgbc = XGBClassifier(**param,use_label_encoder =False)  
       
'''.
For incremental, use xgb_model parameter in fit().
Run the 1st fit() first without xgb_model as parameter, and 
next fits with the xgb_model which contains the model object of the last training.
'''
        
# Fit Model
for i, (X_batch, y_batch) in enumerate(zip(X_train_batched, y_train_batched)):
    print(f'Step: {i}',end = ' ')
    if i == 0:
        model_xgbc.fit(X_batch, y_batch, eval_set=[(X_valid, y_valid)],
                        verbose=False, eval_metric = ['logloss'],
                        early_stopping_rounds = 400)
    else:
        model_xgbc.fit(X_batch, y_batch, eval_set=[(X_valid, y_valid)],
                        verbose=False, eval_metric = ['logloss'],
                        early_stopping_rounds = 400, 
                        xgb_model = model_xgbc
                        )       
    preds = model_xgbc.predict(X_valid)
    
    rmse = metrics.mean_squared_error(y_valid, preds,squared=False)
        
print(rmse)
```